# GIT Smart Http - R any DENIED by fallthru

Tags: git, http, gitolite

I have installed GIT on a Red Hat Linux server to be used for centralized repository and using HTTP username and password to control the user access from our Windows notebook.

Based on the testing.git repo that comes as a sample repository, everything seems fine but when I try to create a new repository, I am getting an error while trying to clone it.

```
C:\Users\kwkoh\messaging>git clone http://10.89.20.91/git/testing.git
Cloning into 'testing'...
remote: Counting objects: 36, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 36 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

On the Linux server, I have created the new repository using the command below

```
[git@a0110tapidev01 repositories]$ git init --bare --shared messaging_v1.git
Initialized empty shared Git repository in /home/git/repositories/messaging_v1.git/

C:\Users\kwkoh\messaging>git clone http://10.89.20.91/git/messaging_v1.git
Cloning into 'messaging_v1'...
****fatal: remote error: FATAL: R any messaging_v1 edmund DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)**

**
```

Since I am not using SSH, I believe I don't need the ssh-keygen related steps. Am I missing any configuration steps for this new repository in `/home/git/repositories/messaging_v1.git/`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you create yourself a bare repo in a git repo hosting server managed with gitolite, said gitolite does not have the opportunity to add [its hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#hooks).

As mentioned [in this section](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#localcode):

> If you add new hooks to this, you must run `gitolite setup`, or at least `gitolite setup --hooks-only`.

Try running at least `gitolite setup --hooks-only` to see if the repo is properly recorded.
If it is not enough, run `gitolite setup`.